# Can the execution time of this prime number generator be improved?

Tags: optimization, f#

My initial goal when writing this was to leave the smallest footprint possible. I can say with confidence that this goal has been met. Unfortunately, this leaves me with a rather slow implementation. To generate all primes below 2 million it takes about 8 seconds on a 3Ghz Intel chip.

Is there anyway to improve the execution time of this code with minimal sacrifice to the small memory footprint? Alternatively, am I going about this the wrong way when looking at it from a functional standpoint?

**CODE**

```
/// 6.5s for max = 2,000,000
let generatePrimeNumbers max =    
    let rec generate number numberSequence =
        if number * number > max then numberSequence else
        let filteredNumbers = numberSequence |> Seq.filter (fun v -> v = number || v % number <> 0L)
        let newNumberSequence = seq { for i in filteredNumbers -> i }
        let newNumber = newNumberSequence |> Seq.find (fun x -> x > number)
        generate newNumber newNumberSequence                
    generate 2L (seq { for i in 2L..max -> i })
```

**Update**

I tweaked the algorithm and managed to shave off 2 seconds but double memory consumption.

```
/// 5.2s for max = 2,000,000
let generatePrimeNumbers max =    
    let rec generate number numberSequence =
        if number * number > max then numberSequence else
        let filteredNumbers = numberSequence |> Seq.filter (fun v -> v = number || v % number <> 0L) |> Seq.toArray |> Array.toSeq
        let newNumber = filteredNumbers |> Seq.find (fun v -> v > number)
        generate newNumber filteredNumbers                
    generate 2L (seq { for i in 2L..max -> i })
```

**Update**

Apparently, I was using an old compiler. With the latest version my original algorithm takes 6.5s rather than 8s. That is quite an improvement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Tomas Petricek's function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053691/can-the-execution-time-of-this-prime-number-generator-be-improved/2054261#2054261) is pretty fast, but we can make it a little faster.

Compare the following:

```
let is_prime_tomas n =
    let ms = int64(sqrt(float(n)))
    let rec isPrimeUtil(m) =
        if m > ms then true
        elif n % m = 0L then false
        else isPrimeUtil(m + 1L)
    (n > 1L) && isPrimeUtil(2L)

let is_prime_juliet n =
    let maxFactor = int64(sqrt(float n))
    let rec loop testPrime tog =
        if testPrime > maxFactor then true
        elif n % testPrime = 0L then false
        else loop (testPrime + tog) (6L - tog)
    if n = 2L || n = 3L || n = 5L then true
    elif n <= 1L || n % 2L = 0L || n % 3L = 0L || n % 5L = 0L then false
    else loop 7L 4L
```

`is_prime_juliet` has a little slightly faster inner loop. Its a well-known prime-generating strategy which uses a "toggle" to skip non-primes in increments of 2 or 4. For comparison:

```
> seq { 2L .. 2000000L } |> Seq.filter is_prime_tomas |> Seq.fold (fun acc _ -> acc + 1) 0;;
Real: 00:00:03.628, CPU: 00:00:03.588, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : int = 148933

> seq { 2L .. 2000000L } |> Seq.filter is_prime_juliet |> Seq.fold (fun acc _ -> acc + 1) 0;;
Real: 00:00:01.530, CPU: 00:00:01.513, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : int = 148933
```

My version is about 2.37x faster, and its also pretty close to the speed of the fastest imperative versions. We can make it *even faster* because we don't need to filter the list of `2L .. 2000000L`, we can use the same strategy to generate a more optimal sequence of possible primes before we apply our filter:

```
> let getPrimes upTo =
    seq {
        yield 2L;
        yield 3L;
        yield 5L;
        yield! (7L, 4L) |> Seq.unfold (fun (p, tog) -> if p <= upTo then Some(p, (p + tog, 6L - tog)) else None)
    }
    |> Seq.filter is_prime_juliet;;
Real: 00:00:00.000, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0

val getPrimes : int64 -> seq<int64>

> getPrimes 2000000L |> Seq.fold (fun acc _ -> acc + 1) 0;;
Real: 00:00:01.364, CPU: 00:00:01.357, GC gen0: 36, gen1: 1, gen2: 0
val it : int = 148933
```

We dropped from 1.530s to 01.364s, so we gained about 1.21x more speed. Awesome!

Comment: Just for completeness, here's some more prime-related functions: http://pastebin.com/f23c064c

Answer (score 7):

Just for funsies, let's take a look at [this page](http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.shtml).

pi(x) is the prime counting function, it returns the number of primes below x. You can approximate pi(x) using the following inequalities:

```
(x/log x)(1 + 0.992/log x) < pi(x) < (x/log x)(1 + 1.2762/log x) 
// The upper bound holds for all x > 1
```

p(x) is the nth's prime function, which can be approximated using:

```
n ln n + n ln ln n - n < p(n) < n ln n + n ln ln n
// for n >= 6
```

With that in mind, [here is a very fast generator](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.ai.genetic/msg/0e6338ae12f1f653?pli=1) which computes the first n primes, where each element at index `i` equal `p(i)`. So, if we want to cap our array at primes below 2,000,000, we use the upperbound inequality for the prime counting function:

```
let rec is_prime (primes : int[]) i testPrime maxFactor =
    if primes.[i] > maxFactor then true
    else
        if testPrime % primes.[i] = 0 then false
        else is_prime primes (i + 1) testPrime maxFactor

let rec prime_n (primes : int[]) primeCount testPrime tog =
    if primeCount < primes.Length then
        let primeCount' =
            if is_prime primes 2 testPrime (float testPrime |> sqrt |> int) then
                primes.[primeCount] <- testPrime
                primeCount + 1
            else
                primeCount
        prime_n primes primeCount' (testPrime + tog) (6 - tog)

let getPrimes upTo =
    let x = float upTo
    let arraySize = int <| (x / log x) * (1.0 + 1.2762 / log x)
    let primes = Array.zeroCreate (max arraySize 3)
    primes.[0] <- 2
    primes.[1] <- 3
    primes.[2] <- 5

    prime_n primes 3 7 4
    primes
```

Cool! So how fast is it? On my 3.2ghz quad-core, I get the following in fsi:

```
> let primes = getPrimes 2000000;;
Real: 00:00:00.534, CPU: 00:00:00.546, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0

val primes : int [] =
  [|2; 3; 5; 7; 11; 13; 17; 19; 23; 29; 31; 37; 41; 43; 47; 53; 59; 61; 67; 71;
    73; 79; 83; 89; 97; 101; 103; 107; 109; 113; 127; 131; 137; 139; 149; 151;
    157; 163; 167; 173; 179; 181; 191; 193; 197; 199; 211; 223; 227; 229; 233;
    239; 241; 251; 257; 263; 269; 271; 277; 281; 283; 293; 307; 311; 313; 317;
    331; 337; 347; 349; 353; 359; 367; 373; 379; 383; 389; 397; 401; 409; 419;
    421; 431; 433; 439; 443; 449; 457; 461; 463; 467; 479; 487; 491; 499; 503;
    509; 521; 523; 541; ...|]

> printfn "total primes: %i. Last prime: %i" (primes.Length - 1) primes.[primes.Length - 1];;
total primes: 149973. Last prime: 2014853
```

So that's all the primes around 2 million in less than half a second :)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT: updated version below, uses less memory and is faster**

Sometimes it's good to be able to mutate stuff. Here's a, admittedly rather imperative, version that trades memory for speed. Since this thread turned out to host a nice collection of prime generating functions in F#, I thought it would be nice to add mine anyway. Using a BitArray keeps memory hogging in check.

```
open System.Collections

let getPrimes nmax =
    let sieve = new BitArray(nmax+1, true)
    let result = new ResizeArray<int>(nmax/10)
    let upper = int (sqrt (float nmax))   
    result.Add(2)

    let mutable n = 3
    while n <= nmax do
       if sieve.[n] then
           if n<=upper then 
               let mutable i = n
               while i <= nmax do sieve.[i] <- false; i <- i + n
           result.Add n
       n <- n + 2
    result
```

*Update:*

The code above can be optimized further: since it only uses the odd indices in the sieve, the BitArray can be reduced to half the size by indexing odd n as 2m+1. The new version is also faster:

```
let getPrimes2 nmax =
    let sieve = new BitArray((nmax/2)+1, true)
    let result = new ResizeArray<int>(nmax/10)
    let upper = int (sqrt (float nmax))   
    if nmax>1 then result.Add(2) //fixes a subtle bug for nmax < 2

    let mutable m = 1
    while 2*m+1 <= nmax do
       if sieve.[m] then
           let n = 2*m+1
           if n <= upper then 
               let mutable i = m
               while 2*i < nmax do sieve.[i] <- false; i <- i + n
           result.Add n
       m <- m + 1
    result
```

Timing (intel core duo 2.33GHz):

```
> getPrimes 2000000 |> Seq.length;;
Real: 00:00:00.037, CPU: 00:00:00.046, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : int = 148933
> getPrimes2 2000000 |> Seq.length;;
Real: 00:00:00.026, CPU: 00:00:00.031, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : int = 148933
```

Answer (score 3):

The imperative version posted by Yin is very fast. On my machine it is also about 0.5sec.
However, if you want to write a simple functional solution you can just write this:

```
let isPrime(n) =
  let ms = int64(sqrt(float(n)))
  let rec isPrimeUtil(m) =
    if m > ms then true
    elif n % m = 0L then false
    else isPrimeUtil(m + 1L)
  (n > 1L) && isPrimeUtil(2L)

[ 1L .. 2000000L ] |> List.filter isPrime
```

This simply tests whether a number is a prime for all numbers to 1 milion. It doesn't use any sophisticated algorithms (it's actually funny that a solution which is simplest is often good enough!). On my machine, your updated version runs about 11 seconds and this runs about 2 seconds.

More interestingly, this is very easy to parallelize. If you use PLINQ you can write the version below and it will run almost 2 times faster on dual core. This means that on quad core, it could be as fast as the fastest solution from all the answers here, but with minimal programming effort :-) (of course, using four cores is not ecological, but.. well)

```
[ 1L .. 2000000L ] |> PSeq.ofSeq |> PSeq.filter isPrime |> List.ofSeq
```

The `PSeq` functions are wrappers for PLINQ that I created for my book (it makes using PLINQ from F# more natural). They are available in [source code for Chapter 14](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/realworldfp).

Comment: I had to give this to Juliet for those optimizations. I'll buy your book as consolation prize. :)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an imperative version, which is faster. It may be impossible to write Sieve of Eratosthenes in a pure functional way to achieve the same speed since you must have a binary state for each number.

```
let generatePrimes max=
    let p = Array.create (max+1) true
    let rec filter i step = 
        if i <= max then 
            p.[i] <- false
            filter (i+step) step
    {2..int (sqrt (float max))} |> Seq.map (fun i->filter (i+i) i) |> Seq.length |> ignore
    {2..max} |> Seq.filter (fun i->p.[i]) |> Seq.toArray
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I love seeing other peoples algorithms. I also hope you are wrong about it being impossible.